# Fastlane Appfile in GIT? How to retrieve current apple_id?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, crashlytics, fastlane

I setup Fastlane for the build automation for my XCode project. At least the Fastfile (containing the build options) should be in GIT, but I would also be happy to have the Appfile (Team Identifiers) also in GIT. The main issue: The Appfile should contain the apple id of me. Sample:

```
apple_id "myid@gmail.com" # Your Apple email address

# Default team ID
team_id "AUE7D4LRRX"

for_platform :ios do
 for_lane :production do
    team_id '-' #reset team id
  end
end
```

Is it somehow possible to dynamically retrieve the apple id from the apple/xcode preferences? In this current solution I would not be able to add this Appfile to GIT since every developer would have it's own version of that file... with a different apple id of course!

Thanks and best regards!

Comment: Maybe pull it out of an environment variable instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can easily set the apple id using an environment variable

**Appfile**

```
apple_id ENV["APPLE_ID"]

...
```

and then run fastlane using

```
APPLE_ID="email@email.com" fastlane beta
```

or similar